# Trouble with Powershell writing to registry

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm writing a script that will modify some registry settings on Windows machines.

I'm using an If to determine if the key/property exist before writing them. It should fail and write an error if it does. This chunk is working:

```psh
$currentPath = 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Ext'
$pathTest = Test-Path $currentPath

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow 'Testing for: ' $currentPath
If($pathTest -ne 'True')
    {
    New-Item -Path $currentPath -Force | Out-Null
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Created Path: '$currentPath
    }
    Else{
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $currentPath ' already exists.'
    }

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow 'Disabling IE Add-On Performance Notifications (DisableAddonLoadTimePerformanceNotifications):'
If((Get-ItemProperty $currentPath -Name 'DisableAddonLoadTimePerformanceNotifications' -ea 0).'DisableAddonLoadTimePerformanceNotifications')
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'DisableAddonLoadTimePerformanceNotifications already exists'
    }
    Else {
         New-ItemProperty -Path $currentPath -Name DisableAddonLoadTimePerformanceNotifications -PropertyType DWord -Value '1' | Out-Null
         Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'DisableAddonLoadTimePerformanceNotifications created and set to 1'
         }
```

It gives me this output if the key/property exists:

```psh
Testing for:  HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Ext
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Ext  already exists.
Disabling IE Add-On Performance Notifications (DisableAddonLoadTimePerformanceNotifications):
DisableAddonLoadTimePerformanceNotifications already exists
```

However, this chunk does not work:

```psh
$currentPath = 'HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main'
$pathTest = Test-Path $currentPath

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow 'Testing for: ' $currentPath
If($pathTest -ne 'True')
    {
    New-Item -Path $currentPath -Force | Out-Null
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Created Path: '$currentPath
    }
    Else{
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $currentPath ' already exists.'
    }

If((Get-ItemProperty $currentPath -Name 'EnableAutoUpgrade' -ea 0).'EnableAutoUpgrade')
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'EnableAutoUpgrade already exists'
    }
    Else{
         New-ItemProperty -Path $currentPath -Name 'EnableAutoUpgrade' -PropertyType DWord -Value '0' | Out-Null
         Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'EnableAutoUpgrade created and set to 0'
    }
```

Output if the key/property exists:

```
Testing for:  HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main  already exists.
New-ItemProperty : The property already exists.
At C:\ps\setup\2.ps1:42 char:10
+          New-ItemProperty -Path $currentPath -Name 'EnableAutoUpgrade' -Property ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...t Explorer\Main:String) [New-ItemProperty], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand

EnableAutoUpgrade created and set to 0
```

Output of the key/property does not exist:

```
Testing for:  HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
Created Path:  HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
Disabling IE Auto Upgrade (EnableAutoUpgrade):
EnableAutoUpgrade created and set to 0
```

So, it'll create the property no problem, but can't see if it already exists.It looks to me like the If is failing on this one, but I can't figure out why. It's the same as one above it. In the full script I run a total of 14 registry entries. The ones above `EnableAutoUpgrade` all work. The ones below `EnableAutoUpgrade` do not and fail with the same error.

This is happening on multiple machines all running Win8.1 and PowerShell v4.

This is a real head scratcher. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$currentPath = "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main"

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Testing for: " $currentPath
If(Test-Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main")
{
Write-Host $currentPath " already exists." -ForegroundColor 'Red' 
}
Else{
   New-Item -Path $currentPath | Out-Null
   Write-Host  "Created Path: "$currentPath -ForegroundColor 'Green'
}
```